# post response from PHP with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How do I post some text to a php doc and then the php doc check's it and returns a response?

In this example checks if entered value is "test" then return and alert TRUE else return and alert FALSE.

**HTML/javascript** (test_php_response.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test_response</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function post_to_php() {

$.post( "test_response.php", function( data ) {
  if (data == true){
      alert("true");
  }else{
     alert("false");
  }
});

}

</script>
</head>


<body>
<a href="javascript:post_to_php();" class='button'>click_here</a>
<form name="response_form"  id="response_form" action="test_response.php" method="POST">
        <input id="response_form_textbox" name="response_form_textbox" type="text"  >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP** *(test_response.php)*

```
<?php
$text_field = $_POST['response_form_textbox'];
if ($text_field == 'test'){
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.patan77.com/test_php/php_response/test_php_response.html)**

**----EDIT solved / working version below:-----**

**HTML/javascript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test_response</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function post_to_php() {

$.post( "test_response.php", $('#response_form').serialize(), function(data) {
  if (data === "true"){
      alert("true");
  }else{
     alert("false");
  }
});

}

</script>
</head>


<body>
<a href="javascript:post_to_php();" class='button'>click_here</a>
<form name="response_form"  id="response_form" action="test_response.php" method="POST">
        <input id="response_form_textbox" name="response_form_textbox" type="text"  >
    </form>
    v.05
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
   <?php
    $text_field = $_POST['response_form_textbox'];
    if ($text_field == 'test'){
        echo 'true';
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: add `method:'POST'` in js

Comment: @aldrin27 `$.post` is a shortcut wrapper for `$.ajax` that already has method set

Comment: What is your question, specifically? It seems like your sample code is already 99% there - are you asking about whether you are parsing the submitted string properly? If the jQuery is working? More specific questions are a lot easier to answer.

Comment: its not working correctly, if I enter test, it should alert true but it don't so I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try to console.log(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sending any data . The second argument of `$.post` is for that data but you omitted it.

Thus in your php `$_POST` will be empty.

The easiest way to send form data is to use `serialize()`

```
$.post( "test_response.php", $('#response_form').serialize(), function( data ) {
  if (data){
      alert("true");
  }else{
     alert("false");
  }
});
```

Reference:

- [serialize() docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
- [$.post() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: have replaced my code with your suggestion in the DEMO and also added console.log(data)  and now I get in the log return false and true correctly but it still only alert false

Comment: inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. Can see exactly what gets sent and what gets returned. In php do a dump of $_POST can see what gets received

Comment: ok have done "dump POST" now and gets this in return:

array(1) { ["response_form_textbox"]=> string(4) "test" } true

Comment: ok...so now need to also understand that the response is a string . Any string sent back will `==` true but will not `=== true`. Response as a javascript variable would be :  `data="true";` not `data=true;`